# How to use list in model value MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list to that I want to pass in a single model value.

```
var playid = (from u in playlist
              select new { u.listtitle, u.Id }).ToList();
```

**Tyring to use it in model-**

```
 var list = new Addvideo
                            {
                                videoname = data.videoname,
                                Ch_Name = data.Ch_Name,
                                videopath = data.videopath,
                                Video_view = Convert.ToInt64(data.Video_View),
                                listname = playid

                            };
```

I want to use both , `listtitle` and `Id` in model entity `listname`.

I have tried this before-

```
listname=playid.Select(m=>new{title=m.listtitle,id=m.Id}).ToList();
```

but this is not working.

Using it view as below-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.listname)
                        {
                            <li><a href="javascript:;">@item</a></li>

                            <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Add to playlist</a></li>
                        }
```

Comment: please can you tell me what you pass as model ? list  or playid

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Addvideo
{
  string videoname {get;set;}
  string Ch_Name {get;set;}
  string videopath {get;set;}
  long Video_view {get;set;}
  IList <Listname> listname {get;set;}
}


public class Listname
{
  string Title {get;set;}
  int Id {get;set;}
}

var playid = (from u in playlist
              select new Listname() { Title = u.listtitle, Id = u.Id }).ToList();

 var list = new Addvideo
                            {
                                videoname = data.videoname,
                                Ch_Name = data.Ch_Name,
                                videopath = data.videopath,
                                Video_view = Convert.ToInt64(data.Video_View),
                                listname = playid    
                            };
```